# Why does my navbar text move to the next row when I only make it visible on XS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like a footer that says something longer in most views but only "Terms" in the XS view.  It works nicely in the full view, but in the XS view it goes to the next row. What am I doing wrong?

http://www.bootply.com/122402

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="navbar-text" id="footerText">©2014 Website</p>    
        <div>
            <p class="navbar-text hidden-xs" id="footerStatement">By using this site you are agreeing to its <a id="termsLink" href="/Terms.htm">terms of use</a></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="navbar-text visible-xs" id="termsLink" href="/Terms.htm">Terms</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right" id="navbarHeaderContact">
        <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" id="contactButton" type="button" data-target="#contact" data-toggle="modal">
                Contact
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footerStatement, #termsLink {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 19px;
}

#termsLink {
    color: #fffff0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get everything onto the same line by changing two things.

1. Move `float: left` into a new block that is not affected by `@media (min-width: 768px)`.

   ```
   .navbar-text {
       float: left;
   }
   ```
2. Remove the extra divs.

   ```
   <div class="container">
       <p id="footerText" class="navbar-text">©2014 Website</p>    
       <p class="navbar-text hidden-xs" id="footerStatement">By using this site you are agreeing to its 
           <a href="/Terms.htm" id="termsLink">terms of use</a>
       </p>
       <a class="navbar-text visible-xs" href="/Terms.htm" id="termsLink">Terms</a>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Thanks. This works well. However, when I zoom the browser font size in and out there is a donut hole in the middle of the range where the footer goes back onto two lines. In other words, the largest and smallest fonts have a one-line footer and certain medium fonts are on two lines. Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, but it's kind of a separate issue. You're using a div with the class `container` inside another element. This div has an explicit width for everything except xs, so it's pushing the button on the right onto a new line. Everything you want in that line should be in the `container` div.

Comment: Once I put everything in the same div, I'm unable to make the contact button pull right.

Comment: I think the problem in general is too many rules that are making things complicated. Use the examples from http://getbootstrap.com and make sure you're using them the way they're intended to be used.

Comment: Are they html/bootstrap rules or CSS rules that are out of hand, or both? (I started with an example with tutorial but in trying to customize it it got out of hand.)

Comment: For example, here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar they have `.navbar` -> `.container` -> `.navbar-header` -> buttons/links/text. You have a deeper hierarchy that starts with `.navbar` -> `.navbar-header` -> `.container`.

Answer (score 2):

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/122425

**HTML** :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-header col-xs-6">
        <div class="container">
            <p id="footerText" class="navbar-text pull-left ">©2014 Website</p> 
        <div>
            <p class="navbar-text hidden-xs" id="footerStatement">By using this site you are agreeing to its <a href="/Terms.htm" id="termsLink">terms of use</a></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="navbar-text visible-xs margin-left pull-left" href="/Terms.htm" id="termsLink">Terms</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right" id="navbarHeaderContact">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact" id="contactButton">
                Contact
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.margin-left{
  margin-left:10px;
  }

#footerStatement, #termsLink {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 19px;
}

#termsLink {
    color: #fffff0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```